# Computing Replacement rate in a renewal process

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

I found this problem on some slides that I'm studying as I prepare for a final:

*"A machine in use is replaced by a new machine either when it fails, or when it reaches the age of $T$ years. If the life times of succesive machines are independent with a common distribution $F$, with density $f$, show that the rate at which the machines are replaced is":
\begin{equation}
\lambda_R=(\int_0^Txf(x)dx+T[1-F(T)])^{-1}
\end{equation}*

**Solution:**

I condition on the first machine, since it is a renewal process, and I also know that $\lambda_R=\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[R_t]}$. So,knowing that the arrival time at which the machine can fail is given by its distribution F, which can happen any time before or after T:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[R_t]=\mathbb{E}[R_t|t<T]P(t<T)+\mathbb{E}[R_t|t>T]P(t>T)
\end{equation}

I break up the parts and get:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[R_t|t<T]=\frac{\int_0^Txf(x)dx}{\int_0^Tf(x)dx}
\end{equation}
where I'm basically getting the centroid of the replacement time $R_t$ for the interval $t<T$.

\begin{equation}
P(t<T)=F(T)
\end{equation}
, where F(T) is the cumulative distribution.

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[R_t|t>T]=T
\end{equation}
because if $t>T$, there will be a reward at time $T$ with probability 1.

\begin{equation}
P(t>T)=1-F(T)
\end{equation}
, and replacing everything :

\begin{equation}
\lambda_R=\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[R_t]}=(\frac{\int_0^Txf(x)dx}{\int_0^Tf(x)dx}F(T)+T(1-F(T)))^{-1}
\end{equation},

but since $F(T)=\int_0^Tf(x)dx$, the left term simplifies and I finally prove the final equation form:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[R_t]=\mathbb{E}[R_t|t<T]P(t<T)+\mathbb{E}[R_t|t>T]P(t>T)
\end{equation}

Does the procedure make sense?

Comment: Yes, this is the proof, decomposed into basic steps.